# How to fix errors on my Linear equation object oriented program?

Tags: java, object

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LinearDrive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 

        System.out.print("Enter value for a: ");
        double a= in.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter value for b: ");
        double b= in.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter value for c: ");
        double c= in.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter value for d: ");
        double d= in.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter value for e: ");
        double e= in.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter value for f: ");
        double f= in.nextDouble();

        Linear linear = new Linear(a,b,c,d,e,f);
        System.out.println("X= "+ linear.getX);
        System.out.println("Y= "+ linear.getY);


    }
}

     public class Linear {

private double a;
private double b;
private double c;
private double d;
private double e;
private double f;

public Linear(double a, double b, double c, double d, double e, double f) {
    this.setA(a);
    this.setB(b);
    this.setC(c);
    this.setD(d);
    this.setE(e);
    this.setF(f);
}

public Linear(){

}


public double getA() {
    return a;
}

public void setA(double a) {
    this.a = a;
}

public double getB() {
    return b;
}

public void setB(double b) {
    this.b = b;
}

public double getC() {
    return c;
}

public void setC(double c) {
    this.c = c;
}

public double getD() {
    return d;
}

public void setD(double d) {
    this.d = d;
}

public double getE() {
    return e;
}

public void setE(double e) {
    this.e = e;
}

public double getF() {
    return f;
}

public void setF(double f) {
    this.f = f;
}

public boolean isSolvable(){
    boolean isSolvable= ((a*d) - (b*c));
    if (isSolvable!=0){
    isSolvable = true;
    }

    return isSolvable;

}

public double otherCase(){
    double otherCase=((a*d) - (b*c));
    if(otherCase==0){
        otherCase="The equation has no solution";
    }

}

public double getX(){
    double x = ((this.e*this.d) - (this.b*this.f)) / ((this.a*this.d) - (this.b*this.c));
    return x;
}

public double getY(){
    double y= ((a*f) - (e*c)) / ((a*d) - (b*c));
    return y;
}
```

}

I am new on this about doing object oriented programs with asking user
  for input. I know I have tons of errors. I need help on how to make my
   methods work

Program: ask user to enter a b c d e f and display result. If ad-bc=0
   report `The equation has no solution

Errors: != is not defined on boolean The equation has no solution
 cannot be converted from string to double, I have tried string can't
 make it work. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved
 compilation problems:      getX cannot be resolved or is not a field
  getY cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: `I know I have tons of errors` what are they? `how to make my methods work` what doesn't work now? try to be as specific as you can.

Comment: May I know why `this.setA(this.a)` is for ??

Comment: 1. `getY()` is commented out 2. if class `Linear` is in another file it should compile and 3. what Henry wrote below

Comment: Ok I already fix that, thank you. Please look at at other errors I added in the top

Comment: The getY and getX are working the problem are the other methods. I don't know how to put the code when asked about displaying true when equation is zero

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
this.setA(this.a);
```

should be

```
this.setA(a);
```

Otherwise the `getX` and `getY` methods seem to be ok. To call them you need to add (), like this:

```
System.out.println("X= "+ linear.getX());
```

To check if the system can be solved you can use a method like this:

```
public boolean isSolvable() {
    return Math.abs(a*b - c*d) > 1e-10;
}
```

Note that you should never compare floating point numbers with `==`. Due to rounding errors results of calculations are almost never exact. The code above uses an interval of 10<sup>-10</sup> to check for a zero determinant.

Comment: I just added the errors I am having in the top

Comment: Most of them are in code that is commented out; furthermore, this code is not called. But: 1) you cannot assign a double value to a boolean variable, 2) you cannot compare a boolean with a number, 3) you cannot assign a String to a double variable, 4) a String literal must be delimited by `"`.

Comment: How can I said that if the equation is 0 display true?

Comment: On public boolean isSolvable() {
    return Math.abs(a*b - c*d) > 1e-10;
}

Comment: How can I add true or The equation has no solution?